# Blackbox testing for SQL injection

Tags: sql-injection

In my college, a security challenge event is going on for one whole month, Participants are expected to 'hack' into a website. The site has a login form, which accepts username and password and POSTs the data to 'connect.php. We don't have the source code available. How can I proceed to audit for SQL Injection vulnerabilities? What should my starting point be? I can use sqlmap, but I couldn't make it work with the web form POST-ing form details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you google this? Here is your answer http://hackertarget.com/sqlmap-post-request-injection/

Comment: Yes, I did before even posting this.

Comment: Ok. Does this answer your question or does login not use post method?

Comment: I executed sqlmap against http://thewebopsclub.org/crypto/, but with no luck.

Comment: I preformed a legal passive scan on this website. I found multiple vulnerability's on this website including sql injection I will post back soon when I put all this together so you can understand it.

Comment: Hi Tim,

This is absolutely legal. Please let me how to approach methodically. I want to learn the art.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20760/discussion-between-tim-williams-and-holmes-sherlock).